# Check whether an object id is present in associated array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have a `Country` model which `has_many` `City`. Having a `Country.name` and `City.name`, how can I check whether the corresponding city is present in the given country's city list?

I started with:

```
Country.where(name: self.country_name).first.cities...
```

But have no idea on what's the best way to check for `City.name` in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query checks if the city is present within the country, based on name:

```
Country.joins(:cities).where(name: country_name, cities: {name: city_name}).any?
```

If you want the record to be returned then:

```
Country.joins(:cities).where(name: country_name, cities: {name: city_name})
```

**Edit**

If you have retrieved the country object on a separate query, you can check if it has a specific city as follows:

```
country = Country.where(name: country_name).first
country.cities.exists?(name: city_name)
```

Which can be combined too:

```
Country.where(name: country_name).first.cities.where(name: city_name).first
```

The difference is this above code executes two queries, one on each table, while using `joins` one query is executed on both tables

Comment: Do I have to put the `joins` part if the models are related?

Comment: I don't see any other way..either `joins` or `includes` doest the job. Country needs to somehow reference the cities table, in the underlying SQL query

Answer (score 0):

```
City.exists?(:name => "name",:country_id=> self.country.id)
```

Comment: I have the country name, not the whole object. I've modified my question to reflect this.

Comment: I have the country name, say 'France'. I need to see if 'Paris' is present in 'France's cities. So, I need to get the country object first in order to be able to use its id.

Comment: Ohh , so you either do joins as alireza said or Country.where(name: self.country_name).first.cities.pluck(:name).includes?(city_name)